# Robolectric's RoboAttributeSet is never read

Tags: android, robolectric

Looks like `RobotoAttributeSet` created and passed to a custom view is never read or constructed incorrectly.

Here is my test:

```
ArrayList<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
    attributes.add(
        new Attribute("com.package.name:attr/CustomButton_inputType",
            String.valueOf(2), "com.package.name")); // no matter what value I use (2)

    AttributeSet attrs =
        new RoboAttributeSet(attributes, Robolectric.application.getResources(), CustomButton.class);

    CustomButton button = new CustomButton(Robolectric.application, attrs);
```

Here is my `attr.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="CustomButton">
    <attr name="inputType" format="enum">
      <enum name="text" value="0"/>
      <enum name="textEmailAddress" value="1"/>
      <enum name="password" value="2"/>
    </attr>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

A part of CustomButton:

```
private void applyAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray typedArray = context.getTheme()
        .obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomButton, 0, 0);

    try {
      int typeValue = // is always 0
          typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.CustomButton_inputType, 0);
      switch (typeValue) {
        case 0:
// do something
          break;
        case 1:
// do something
          break;
        case 2:
          // do something
          break;
        default:
          // just do nothing
          break;
      }
    } finally {
      typedArray.recycle();
    }
  }
```

So no matter what value I set when preparing attributes (it is `2` in the example), I always get `0` for `typeValue`.

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've tried to similar at my setup and also confirm that styledArray is empty. However I see that it is not empty when I try to inflate view from Activity and xml resource. Would you consider about this way of testing?

Comment: I created a ticket https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1478

Answer (score 3):

The issue comes from your test, especially the value passed to the AttributeSet.
Indeed, instead of passing the value field of the enum, you should pass the name field of the enum, so you can, latter on your view, get the associated value field.

```
attributes.add(
    new Attribute("com.package.name:attr/CustomButton_inputType",
        "textEmailAddress", "com.package.name"));
```

Hope this could help :)
Also, do not hesitate to go and look at [my post dealing with custom attributes](http://turhanoz.com/custom-attributes-for-custom-android-component/).

Comment: Turhan Oz, no, passing the name of the field doesn't solve the problem - it's always zero either way.

Comment: Strange. Which version of Robolectric are you using ? Try with 2.2  (the one against I have checked)

Comment: I'm using 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
attributes.add(
        new Attribute("com.package.name:attr/inputType",
            String.valueOf(2), "com.package.name"));
```